# How to fix type inference for a component variable in a jest Shallow test built with reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, type-inference, shallow-copy

My scenario is a react project built in typescript, and specifically regarding a unit test involving `shallow` from Enzyme.
I'm working on aligning the project with the tsconfig parameter `"noImplicitAny": true,`
I'm wondering how to fix the let component issue described under.

```
let component

beforeEach(() => {
  component = shallow(<MyComponent format="%MM : %SS" />)
})

describe('#render', () => {
  it('shows the component correctly', () => {
    expect(component.find('.my-component').exists()).toEqual(true)
  })
})
```

error

```
Variable 'component' implicitly has type 'any' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.ts(7034)
```

how to create the inference of type `MyComponent` to variable `component`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to type the `component` variable as a `ShallowWrapper`, with the generic type parameter of `MyComponent`. This is how it can be done:

```
import { shallow, ShallowWrapper } from 'enzyme';

let component: ShallowWrapper<MyComponentProps>;
component = shallow<MyComponentProps>(<MyComponent format="%MM : %SS" />)
```

Comment: I added, still issue is the same, but I guess because still component is not initialised as any type.

Comment: @axel ok, I have updated my answer. This should work.

Comment: now it gives me this error => `'MyComponent' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof MyComponent'? ts(2749)`

Comment: Yeah you might have to use `<typeof MyComponent>`

Comment: Should I not use `let component: ShallowWrapper<MyCompnentProps>` and `component = shallow(<MyComponent format="%MM : %SS" />)`?

Comment: If you do something like this, `const component = shallow(<MyComponent format="%MM : %SS" />)`, there will be no need for the additional type declaration since TypeScript will be able to infer the types when you assign it to a `const`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215085/discussion-between-axel-and-wentjun).